# How do I reset scroll position of paper-dialog-scrollable?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a `paper-dialog` with a `paper-dialog-scrollable` how do I reset the scroll position of the dialog everytime its open/closed?

**UPDATE**

```
<paper-dialog-scrollable id="disclaimerScroller">
```

---

When I open the modal,

```
this.$.disclaimer.open();
Polymer.dom(this.$.disclaimerScroller).scrollTop = 0;

// I also tried 
this.$.disclaimerScroller.scrollTop = 0
```

It does not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add and event listener `iron-overlay-opened` in `paper-dialog` which will fire after the `paper-dialog` is opened. In that listener you can simply put your code to reset the scroll position of the `paper-dialog-scrollable`.

Example Code:

```
<paper-dialog id="scrolling" on-iron-overlay-opened="onIronOverlayOpened">

<paper-dialog-scrollable id="disclaimerScroller">

onIronOverlayOpened(){       
   this.$.disclaimerScroller.$.scrollable.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mIp961msrq4cogDl?p=preview)

Comment: Hmm but I didnt try `this.$.disclaimerScroller.$.scrollable.scrollTop = 0;` I used `this.$.disclaimerScroller.scrollTarget.scrollTop = 0` instead. What does `$.scrollable` refer to? Is that documented?

Comment: No, this is not documented. `$.scrollable` refers to the `div` inside `paper-dialog-scrollable` that has the scrollbar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scrollTop` property. So for example: `this.$.scrollableDialog.scrollTop = 0`.

Comment: This did not seem to work for me I tried this. Updated my original post

Comment: I am not using this element, but in code i found property `scrollTarget`. so something like `this.$.disclaimerScroller.scrollTarget.scrollTop = 0;`

Comment: I tried `this.$.disclaimerScroller.scrollTarget.scrollTop = 0` but it didnt work either. Where do you find docs on this? Like how do you know you need scrollTarget for example

Comment: all polymerElements are open source. so you can go on https://www.webcomponents.org and find elemnt you are looking for. In detail of element there is a documentation and link to github repo where is source code. And BTW, I just tried `.scrollTarget.scrollTop = 0` and it works. So problem is somewhere else in your code. Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: I think maybe it didnt work because I called this immediately after `open()`. My guess is I set this before the dialog is open thus it failed (no errors tho). Calling on `on-iron-overlay-opened` fixes it

Comment: @JiewMeng Did you check my answer?

Comment: @Ofisora ops I missed that. Once I solved it I came here just to mark answered but didnt see yours, let me mark it as answer :) Thank You